# How can partial/complete mediation be tested outside the causal steps approach?

Tags: regression, causality, mediation

Hayes (2018) writes on p.146

> Statistical mediation analysis has changed since the publication of
> Baron and Kenny (1986). The heyday of the causal steps “criteria to
> establish mediation” approach is over. Also disappearing in the 21st
> century is a concern about whether a process can be labeled as
> complete or partial mediation.

This is in the context of a chapter at which Hayes writes at length about why the causal steps approach is flawed and should not be used, and also argues that the notions of partial and complete mediation "are empty concepts and should be abandoned" (p. 119).

My question isn't a practical one as I'm not planning to do a causal steps mediation analysis, or to test for partial or complete mediation.

I'm just wondering about the independence of these two concepts. How can one test for partial/complete mediation outside the context of the causal steps approach? In practice, is it common for people to test for partial/complete mediation outside the context of the causal steps approach?

Hayes, A. F. (2018). Introduction to mediation, moderation, and conditional process analysis: A regression-based approach. Guilford publications.